# remove href class in a div 3 levels up

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get my accordion menu to collapse by default, if a child li class is set to open. I have the following markup

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Cleaning and Painting</a> </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="collapse1" >

        <ul class="links">
          <li class="l1 open"> <a href="air-compressor.html">Air Compressor</a> </li>
          <li class="l2"> <a href="paint-sprayer.html">Paint Sprayer</a> </li>
          <li class="lL"> <a href="pressure-cleaner.html">Pressure Cleaner</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tied with the following, but it does not remove the class "collapsed"

```
  if( $('.accordion-inner .links li').hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).closest('div.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle').removeClass("collapsed");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle. Can't see any element with class `accordion-inner`

Comment: .accordion-inner is missing

Comment: The basic problem is: It is not "3 levels up", it is actually "3 levels up then 1 div across" :)  *The elements are in different branches*. Ignore any suggestions of using `parents`. Using `closest` is more efficient. You just need to go up 4 levels then search down.

Comment: there is only one accordion on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the missing `.accordion-inner` for now, the problem is that your clicked anchor element is in a different branch of the DOM to the `a.accordion-toggle`.

Instead go up to the `accordion-group` class (using closest) then `find` down to the `accordion-toggle` within that group:

```
$(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('a.accordion-toggle').removeClass("collapsed");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cwfgvbzh/5/

*Credit to @Simple Man for creating the JSFiddle for me and spotting I was missing a `.` in one selector.*

Comment: Note: I was initially missing a full stop in one selector, which somehow caused all manner of confusion with Simple Man :)

Comment: Thanks for resolving everything.

Comment: @Simple Man: I had not even noticed the missing `.` until you finally mentioned it an hour later. I thought one of us (at least) was going mad :)

Comment: My simple goal is to serve at my best. :)